# Include and iterate over similar HtmlElements blocks in page

Tags: java, selenium, htmlelements

I decided to try out yandex HtmlElements framework to construct page that contains several similar blocks. Intention was to describe single block in separate class with all its methods and then iterate over list of them in main page.

Following example from https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements, I made following:

**Section class**:

```
@FindBy(xpath = ".//div[@class='score-section']")
public class Section extends HtmlElement {

        @Timeout(10)
        @FindBy(xpath = ".//div[@class='account-title']")
        private WebElement accountTitle;

        public void printValues() {
            System.out.println(accountTitle.getText());
        }
```

**Page class**:

```
public class MainPage extends BasePage {
public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(new HtmlElementLocatorFactory(driver)), this);
    }

List<Section> sections;

public void iterateOverSections() {
    for (Section section : sections) {
        section.printValues();
    }
}
```

However, I get NoSuchElementException for accountTitle.

Is it possible (and how?) to construct page from similar blocks?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any problems in your code, can you show html page you test?

Comment: Actually, everything works. Problem is with specific web element that I picked for test. I just used another element, and it was found.